# SwiftData Error: Failed to find any currently loaded container for Deck)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

## Problem

I was using swift data on my project in what I thought was a not very complex data model and then after I added the delete function it gave me this error and crashed the simulator every time.

```
DataModel

import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Deck {
    var name: String
    var cards: String
    
    
    init(name: String, cards: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.cards = cards
    }
}
```

And this is where I was fetching the data.

## DeckView

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct DeckView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var decks: [Deck]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.background
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                List {
                    ForEach(decks) { deck in
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(deck.name)
                                Text(deck.cards)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                // Action
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteDeck)
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Decks")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .onTapGesture {
                           // showingSheet.toggle()
                           addSamples()
                        }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                NewDeckSheet()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addSamples() {
        let swiftd = Deck(name: "SwiftData", cards: "20")
        let swifty = Deck(name: "Swift", cards: "21")
        let swiftyui = Deck(name: "SwiftUI", cards: "32")
        
        modelContext.insert(swiftd)
        modelContext.insert(swifty)
        modelContext.insert(swiftyui)
    }
    
    func deleteDeck(_ indexSet: IndexSet) {
        for index in indexSet {
            let deck = decks[index]
            modelContext.delete(deck)
        }
    }
    
}
```

## What the console returns

```
Deck = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x600002c88790>) name Deck, managedObjectClassName NSManagedObject, renamingIdentifier Deck, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    cards = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000035a9080>), name cards, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Deck, renamingIdentifier cards, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 300 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO, allowsCloudEncryption NO\";\n    name = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000035a9100>), name name, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Deck, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO, allowsCloudEncryption NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, destinationModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x6000038a69e0>) isEditable 0, entities {
    Deck = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x600002c84420>) name Deck, managedObjectClassName Deck, renamingIdentifier Deck, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    cards = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x60000359f680>), name cards, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Deck, renamingIdentifier cards, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO, allowsCloudEncryption NO\";\n    name = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x60000359f580>), name name, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Deck, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO, allowsCloudEncryption NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, reason=Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000156cb70 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134190 "(null)" UserInfo={entity=Deck, property=cards, reason=Source and destination attribute types are incompatible}}}
```

And then: `SwiftData/ModelContainer.swift:144: Fatal error: failed to find a currently active container for Deck` And: `Failed to find any currently loaded container for Deck)` 
Any help would be appreciated, **thank you!**

I tried commenting out everything else related to SwiftData such as the delete function and such but it would still crash the sim. I was expecting it to display the Decks in the model when I clicked the + tab item but it crashed the sim.

Comment: Where do you inject the container?

Comment: In the app file for all the views.

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct CardSpaceApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainTabView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: Deck.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it crash o simulator or canvas?

Comment: It crashes the simulator when I press the + nevigation bar item and the canvas.

Comment: To me it looks like you have made some changes to your model and SwiftData fails to perform a migration from the old to the new version. If this is correct the easiest solution is to delete your current sqlite file so that SwiftData can generate a new one from scratch.

Comment: Where do I find that?

Comment: Add the following launch argument to the scheme you use in Xcode to run the app, `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`. Then the path to the file will be printed in the console when you launch the app.

Comment: CoreData: sql: SELECT MAX(Z_PK) FROM ATRANSACTION?

Comment: First of all, if you want quicker response you should tag your comments with the persons name you are addressing (@<name>), secondly I am a little surprised you don’t recognize a file path. It starts with /Users/… and was one of the first thing printed in the console when the app was launched.